# Find the minimum sum of distances between sets of points to a straight line in a plane

Tags: data-structures, runtime-analysis, arrays, partitions, selection-problem

Given $n$ dots on a plane, such as: n couples ($x_i$,$y_i$)
I would like to find a line parallel to y-axis ( $x=b$ ), such that the sum of all of the point's distances from that line will be minimal

In order to do that, I need to write an alogrithem with a **linear** run-time ( $O(n)$ )

> MY METHOD
>  I relate only for the $x$ values of each point as an
> element in an Array called $A$
>  So I used the `Select(A,left, right, p)` & `Partition` Alogorithm in order to find the median of
> medians of the array

pseudo-code:

```
Select(A,left,right,p)
 n<-right-left+1
 if n=1 then
  return A[left]
 m<-⌈n/5⌉
 let B array with length m
 for i <-1 to m
  B[i]=medianOf5(A,left,right,x)
 x<-Select(B,1,m, ⌈m/2⌉) 
 q <- partition(A,left,right,x)
 k <-q-left+1
 if p<k then
  return Select(A,left,q,p)
 if p>k 
  return Select(A,q,right,p)
```

But, using median of medians seems unnecessary
If so, is there an easier way to that? if not ( or if yes for that matter ) was my way correct?

Comment: I think that's correct, and I don't think there is a better way to guarantee $O(n)$ worst case.

Comment: See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139131/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/138872/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/48817/5038, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67200191/781723, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113270/14578, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7307/2921.

Answer (score 1):

Given a line $L = b$, the distance from any point $(x, y)$ to $L$ is
$\left| y - b\right|$.

The sum of a distances for a set of points $S = \{(x_1, y_1), \dots,
(x_n, y_n)\}$ is then
$$\left| y_1 - b \right| + \cdots + \left| y_n - b \right|$$
which is minimized for which $b$?

Comment: But you should take only the $x's$ in order to determine the distance

Comment: @omribraha that doesn't make much of a difference, but yes, of it's a vertical line, you pick the xs.

Comment: And yet, I did not understand, how from that I can determine which is minimized for which $b$ and if my Algorithm has a simpler solution

Comment: @OmriBraha Okay, if it is only two numbers, what do we call the answer then?  I.e., you have $\{y_1, y_2\}$.